# Passing Parameter to Crystal Reports XI from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2015, parameter-passing

I am running into problems with the passing of parameters to an externally created **Crystal Reports XI** report from the WinForms application I'm building in **Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition**.  No matter what I try to do, the report doesn't seem to get the value unless I manually select it at the prompt (*which shouldn't even be popping up*) when the report is being displayed.  I'm using the same code I've used in a previous application (although that one was built in **VS2008**), but I've tried a number of "alternate" versions of the code in my attempts to get this working.  Here's the code that I'm currently using:

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

Module modReports
    Private WithEvents DocumentToPrint As New Printing.PrintDocument
    Private Sub ShowReport(ByVal LID As Integer, ByVal InHouse As Boolean)
        Dim Report As New ReportDocument
        Dim ReportParameters As ParameterFieldDefinitions = Nothing
        Dim Parameter As ParameterFieldDefinition = Nothing
        Dim ApplicationValue As ParameterDiscreteValue = Nothing
        Dim ReportValues As ParameterValues = Nothing
        Dim ReportViewer As New frmReport
        Dim Response As DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel

        PrintingReport = True
        Report.Load(CRYSTAL_REPORT_FILE_PATH & "ExampleReport.rpt")
        Report.Refresh()
        Report.VerifyDatabase()

        ReportParameters = Report.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
        Parameter = ReportParameters.Item("PrintAll")

        ReportValues = New ParameterValues
        ApplicationValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue
        'Parameter.CurrentValues.Clear()
        'ReportValues.Clear()
        ReportValues = Parameter.CurrentValues

        If LID = 7777 Then
            ApplicationValue.Value = True
        Else
            ApplicationValue.Value = False
        End If

        ReportValues.Add(ApplicationValue)
        Parameter.ApplyCurrentValues(ReportValues)

        Response = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to send this report directly to the printer?", "SEND TO PRINTER", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

        If Response = DialogResult.No Then
            With ReportViewer
                .rptViewer.ReportSource = Nothing
                .rptViewer.ReportSource = Report
                .WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
                .rptViewer.RefreshReport()
                ' Set zoom level: 1 = Page Width, 2 = Whole Page, 25-100 = zoom %
                .rptViewer.Zoom(1)
                .rptViewer.Show()
                .ShowDialog()
            End With
        ElseIf Response = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Dim SelectPrinter As New PrintDialog
            Dim PrinterSelected As DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel

            With SelectPrinter
                .Document = DocumentToPrint
                .AllowPrintToFile = False
                .AllowSelection = False
                .AllowCurrentPage = False
                .AllowSomePages = False
                .PrintToFile = False
            End With

            PrinterSelected = SelectPrinter.ShowDialog

            If PrinterSelected = DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim Copies As Integer = DocumentToPrint.PrinterSettings.Copies
                Dim PrinterName As String = DocumentToPrint.PrinterSettings.PrinterName
                Dim LastPageNumber As Integer = 1
                Dim PrintBuffer As String = String.Empty

                LastPageNumber = Report.FormatEngine.GetLastPageNumber(New ReportPageRequestContext)
                Report.PrintOptions.PrinterName = PrinterName
                Report.PrintOptions.PrinterDuplex = DocumentToPrint.PrinterSettings.Duplex
                Report.PrintToPrinter(Copies, True, 1, LastPageNumber)

                If Copies = 1 Then
                    PrintBuffer = "Printed " & Copies & " copy of "
                Else
                    PrintBuffer = "Printed " & Copies & " copies of "
                End If

                If LastPageNumber = 1 Then
                    PrintBuffer += LastPageNumber.ToString & " page."
                Else
                    PrintBuffer += LastPageNumber.ToString & " pages."
                End If

                MessageBox.Show("The report was sent to the following printer:" & vbCrLf & " • " & PrinterName & vbCrLf & PrintBuffer, "REPORT PRINTED", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
        End If

        PrintingReport = False
    End Sub
End Module
```

The report itself is built to use an XML file as the data source, which is dynamically created by this application.  All of that works normally, and oddly enough, if I send the report directly to the printer, it seems to print correctly without prompting me.  It's only a problem when I try to display the report through the CrystalReportViewer object.

Some of the things I've tried without success:

- I've tried with and without calling the `Clear()` methods on the
  `Parameter.CurrentValues` and `ReportValues` objects.
- I've tried moving all of the parameter setting logic to after I set the
  `ReportSource` of the CrystalReportViewer control (`rptViewer.ReportSource`)
- I've tried using alternate Crystal Reports objects (`ParameterFields` instead of `ParameterFieldDefinitions` and `ParameterField` instead of `ParameterFieldDefinition`).
- I've tried removing all of the "complicated" code and just using the `SetParameterValue` method (i.e., `Report.SetParameterValue("PrintAll", True)`
- I've even tried creating different types of parameter fields in the report itself (String, Boolean, Number) and passing appropriate values for those datatypes.

If I walk through the code, it doesn't appear to error out anywhere, and everything looks like it's working just great until I get to the `.rptViewer.RefreshReport()` line in the `With ReportViewer` block.  I've verified that all of the parameters and values have only the value I am "selecting" via the application by checking them every step up to that point, and it all looks exactly as I expect it to look.

But the application (via Crystal Reports) continues to prompt me for the value I just passed in the code.  If I select the value in that prompt, the report *does* generate correctly based on the value I select, but no matter what I "pass" in the programming, the prompt always defaults to `True`.

Does anyone have any suggestions that I may have overlooked for how to get this parameter to correctly pass to the CrystalReportViewer control?  Please let me know if you need any additional information or have any questions about what I've set up so far here.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so based on the information I found over on http://www.it-sideways.com/2011/10/how-to-disable-parameter-prompt-for.html, it seems that the `RefreshReport` method for the **CrystalReportViewer** control basically wipes out any parameters and/or log on information:

> **1. ) Do not invoke CrystalReportViewer.RefreshReport Method**
>
> This method will refresh the data for the report currently displayed
>   in the CrystalReportViewer control. The report will prompt for
>   parameters or logon info is necessary.
>
> So, this method is not needed unless the same
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument object is
>   reused.

By commenting out that line of the code, I was able to prevent the parameter prompt from being displayed.  The only issue I have after making that change is that, even though the zoom level is being set to `1` (page width), and when I run the project the **CrystalReportViewer** control even shows that it's correctly set in the status bar ('*Zoom Factor: Page Width*' is displayed), the report itself is not actually zoomed in to the page width.

With the `RefreshReport` method uncommented, if I manually provided the value for my parameter, it would display the report properly zoomed.  If I add the zoom button to the control (`.rptViewer.ShowZoomButton = True`), I can manually choose the Page Width option, which then correctly "re-zooms" the report to the desired level, but it won't immediately display that way if the `RefreshReport` method is not called.

Regardless, I can spend some time trying to fight that now, but I finally have it properly setting, passing and displaying the results of my parameter.  I hope this helps someone else running into this issue.